# How to determine retransmission statistics on the Android platform?

Tags: android, android-networking

On linux, we can use something like `netstat -s` and get something like the following:

```
netstat -s | grep retrans
    8411 segments retransmitted
    1 timeouts after reno fast retransmit
    874 fast retransmits
    113 retransmits in slow start
```

The netstat version on Android doesn't have this functionality. How can we determine retransmission statistics on the Android platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find retransmission statistics by doing the following in shell

```
TB-8504F:/ $ cat /proc/net/netstat                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
TcpExt: SyncookiesSent SyncookiesRecv SyncookiesFailed EmbryonicRsts PruneCalled RcvPruned OfoPruned OutOfWindowIcmps LockDroppedIcmps ArpFilter TW TWRecycled TWKilled PAWSPassive PAWSActive PAWSEstab DelayedACKs DelayedACKLocked DelayedACKLost ListenOverflows ListenDrops TCPPrequeued TCPDirectCopyFromBacklog TCPDirectCopyFromPrequeue TCPPrequeueDropped TCPHPHits TCPHPHitsToUser TCPPureAcks TCPHPAcks TCPRenoRecovery TCPSackRecovery TCPSACKReneging TCPFACKReorder TCPSACKReorder TCPRenoReorder TCPTSReorder TCPFullUndo TCPPartialUndo TCPDSACKUndo TCPLossUndo TCPLostRetransmit TCPRenoFailures TCPSackFailures TCPLossFailures TCPFastRetrans TCPForwardRetrans TCPSlowStartRetrans TCPTimeouts TCPLossProbes TCPLossProbeRecovery TCPRenoRecoveryFail TCPSackRecoveryFail TCPSchedulerFailed TCPRcvCollapsed TCPDSACKOldSent TCPDSACKOfoSent TCPDSACKRecv TCPDSACKOfoRecv TCPAbortOnData TCPAbortOnClose TCPAbortOnMemory TCPAbortOnTimeout TCPAbortOnLinger TCPAbortFailed TCPMemoryPressures TCPSACKDiscard TCPDSACKIgnoredOld TCPDSACKIgnoredNoUndo TCPSpuriousRTOs TCPMD5NotFound TCPMD5Unexpected TCPSackShifted TCPSackMerged TCPSackShiftFallback TCPBacklogDrop TCPMinTTLDrop TCPDeferAcceptDrop IPReversePathFilter TCPTimeWaitOverflow TCPReqQFullDoCookies TCPReqQFullDrop TCPRetransFail TCPRcvCoalesce TCPOFOQueue TCPOFODrop TCPOFOMerge TCPChallengeACK TCPSYNChallenge TCPFastOpenActive TCPFastOpenActiveFail TCPFastOpenPassive TCPFastOpenPassiveFail TCPFastOpenListenOverflow TCPFastOpenCookieReqd TCPSpuriousRtxHostQueues BusyPollRxPackets TCPAutoCorking TCPFromZeroWindowAdv TCPToZeroWindowAdv TCPWantZeroWindowAdv TCPSynRetrans TCPOrigDataSent
TcpExt: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 37 0 0 0 0 0 151 0 82 0 0 22 0 2320 0 8335 5 278 74 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 65 43 1 0 1 0 0 81 0 0 0 48 44 0 53 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1600 132 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 64 751
IpExt: InNoRoutes InTruncatedPkts InMcastPkts OutMcastPkts InBcastPkts OutBcastPkts InOctets OutOctets InMcastOctets OutMcastOctets InBcastOctets OutBcastOctets InCsumErrors InNoECTPkts InECT1Pkts InECT0Pkts InCEPkts
IpExt: 0 0 385 248 683 0 3790846 363856 14808 11056 68971 0 0 6861 0 0 0
```